# How can I verify if a retrieved price corresponds to the product I want to track?

Tags: python, web-scraping, tags

I am developing a Python scraping script. For the moment, I can give the script a product name, for instance 'Fifa 17' and with an algorithm, it gives me about 3 to 4 links where the product can be bought (Amazon, Priceminister for instance).

Then, I scrape the html code of the page which is selling the product with the following python snippet :

```
url = 'http://www.priceminister.com/mfp/5470023'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.90 Safari/537.36'}
page = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
contenu = page.content
```

The 'contenu' var contains all the HTML.
This is the priceminister web page for ordering Fifa 17 here. I'd like to extract from this code the price of Fifa 17. With regular expressions, I can already match the currency symbols like "€" or "$", but the page contains also other product prices so it's not reliable. I was thinking about matching the title tag with contains something like "Fifa 17" and then get the first price tag but if you have an original price first and a sale price secondly, you'd rather get the sale one. So this method does not work either ...

I can't give straight XPATH links to match in the code because my code has to work for other websites, so I can't cheat by knowing priceminister page design ...

Because, of course, I can cheat and look with my browser which HTML tag contains the price of Fifa 17 and give it straight to the code but if I do this way, I will be non-generic, I'll have to find the tags for each website. And I don't want it, I want the script to be generic so that it should, in theory, work for every website.

I am running out of ideas, if someone could help ...

Comment: I can get the price with jQuery selector `$("#prdBuyBoxV2.p.price.typeUsed.spacerBottomXs")`, I would use [beautifulsoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) to reliably parse the html

Comment: @fedterzi  
Yes, indeed it works, but as I mentioned, you kinda cheat here, because you know that on this website, the price tag is called "p.price.typeUsed.spacerBottomXs". So it won't work on other websites such as Amazon where the tag is different.

Comment: Many of the world's masters at associating search strings with related objects are employed at google. If you consider what might be a comparable problem, that of associating natural language words and phrases with images I think it's clear that even google has trouble doing it. There's just too much noise on any given page.

Comment: @Bill Bell  Alright, I understand what you mean. Maybe it's too ambitious and I should retrieve the 2 to 3 first price tags and see if it corresponds to the expected price instead ...

Comment: I learned long ago to avoid saying the words 'you can't do that'. (There's always another programmer up the hall who can make you look a fool by doing it.) But sometimes you can't.

Answer (score 1):

One way I can think to the general approach is valuing the importance of each price you retrieved on the page. For example, a price under a 'h1' tag would be more important than a little price placed at the corner of the page. Maybe there are some libraries that do this, but I can't think of any of them right now.

Anything you do, though, would require an intelligent way of discriminating the prices. And while you may find a good approach, this approach won't work for each and every site you find.

So, probably, "cheating" here is the easiest solution. You can just create selectors for each site and roll with it.

Comment: I was working on a decision algorithm and yes, you're right the closer to the title it'll be, the more relevant it should be. In the idea, it's a project where I have to make a generic application so I can't cheat unfortunately (I would do it if it was for personal use) ...

Comment: Oh, I see... If I were you I'd just try lots of different methods then! And combine the ones that work better at the end. This way you may get a robust algorithm. You would just need to fine tune it with lots of different sites.

Comment: Still, there can be ways out there I don't know about. Wondering how Google does it... [look at this](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=buy+fifa+17)

Comment: Yeah it's pretty hard to figure out how they can achieve this but you got exactly what I meant, that's exactly why I'd like to do ...